# Check if an update succeeded in MySql

Tags: mysql, transactions

I use an `update` inside a stored procedure that's inside a `loop` (a loop which fetches rows and goes through them one row at a time).

How can I tell if the update in there actually succeeded, so based on it's success, I can update something else?

**Example:**

```
OPEN cur1;
    read_loop: LOOP
        IF done THEN
             LEAVE read_loop;
          END IF;

update tabs set checked = 1 where id = tabId

-- Only If the above update succeeded, I'd like to set another col to 1

If /* Above update succeeded */ then
update tabs set updated = 1 where id = tabId
```

How is this actually done? Is there anything in MySql that can check for an updates success?

Comment: this appears to be a question about transactions

Comment: Do you mean if the checked was previously other than 1?
I mean the update will always succesful if the row exists.
Or you would like to test if the row exists? Then you can add an extra exists clause to the other/related query.

Comment: @LajosVeres No. I'm only trying to check if any update was successfully performed.

Comment: @jmenezes why don't you set both checked and updated to one within the same statement then if it fails neither would be updated...

Answer (score 0):

to check if update success use the mysql command : ROW_COUNT()

```
OPEN cur1;
    read_loop: LOOP
        IF done THEN
             LEAVE read_loop;
          END IF;

update tabs set checked = 1 where id = tabId;

-- Only If the above update succeeded, I'd like to set another col to 1

If ROW_COUNT()>0 THEN
  update tabs set updated = 1 where id = tabId;
END IF;
```

for more information : [MySql ROW_COUNT command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//information-functions.html#function_row-count)